# append value to each item in list and add to new list using robot framework

Tags: robotframework

Below is my first list:

```
list_1: ['0', '3']
```

I would like to add an alphabet before each of the above item and save in another list as below:

```
list_2: ['a0','a3']   ###This should be final result
```

Please let me know how this can be achieved using Robot Framework.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the elements in the source list, append the string to each of them, and add the result in the new list.

```
${list_2}=    Create List
FOR    ${el}    IN    @{list_1}
    ${new el}=     Set Variable    a${el}
    Append To List    ${list_2}    ${new el}
END
Log To Console    ${list_2}    # ['a0','a3']
```